# How to get column data in column names in query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have the following table:

```
 Cust Prod     Qty
===== ====     ===
 Bob   Apple    3
 Bob   Orange   2
 Bob   Banana   4
 Rob   Apple    2
 Rob   Orange   1
 Bob   Apple    2
```

How can I get the following result with the table data as the column names:

```
Prod   Bob Rob
====== === ===
Apple    5   2
Orange   2   1
Banana   4  null
```

Comment: `select * from tablename pivot( sum(qty) for cust in([Bob],[Rob])) group by Cust`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in MSSQL or the following way:

```
SELECT
PROD,
SUM(CASE WHEN Cust='Bob' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) as Bob,
SUM(CASE WHEN Cust='Rob' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) as Rob

FROM T
GROUP BY PROD
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56822/2)</kbd>

Comment: Instead of 0, can I use NULL and what does PIVOT do?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from t
pivot
(
  sum(Qty)
  for [Cust] in ([Bob],[Rob])
)as p;
GROUP BY PROD
```

## [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56822/5)